# How do I get these properties to not be undefined when they're in an embed

Tags: node.js, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const prefix1 = '*add'
const prefix2 = '*what'
const prefix3 = '*remove'
const prefix4 = '*search'
const bot4 = new Discord.Client();
let a = []
let fakea = []
bot4.on('message', msg => {
    
    
if(msg.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')){    
    if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix1)){

    let splited = msg.content.split(' ')
    let unchanged = msg.content.split(' ')
    splited.splice('*info', 1)
    splited.splice(msg.content[1], 1)
    splited.splice(msg.content[2], 1)
    let c = splited.join(' ')
    
    
    b = {
        namer: unchanged[1],
        imformation: unchanged[2],
        description: c
    }
    
    if(fakea.includes(unchanged[1])){
        msg.channel.send('It already exists')
    } else {
        a.push(b) 
        fakea.push(unchanged[1])
    }
    console.log(a)
    }
    if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix3)){
        let armay = msg.content.split(' ')
        console.log(a)
        console.log(fakea)
        if(armay.length != 2){
            msg.channel.send(`You have either less or more than two words. That either means you wrote *add on it's own or you had more than one word that you put with the command`)

        } else {
            if(!fakea.includes(armay[1])){
                msg.channel.send(`That doesn't exist. You can't delete something that doesn't exist.`)

            } else {
                let fakeafind = fakea.find(plot => plot === armay[1])
                let afind = a.find(plote => plote.namer === armay[1])
                fakea.splice(fakeafind, 1)
                a.splice(afind, 1)
            }
        console.log(a)
        console.log(fakea)
        }
    }
if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix2)){
    let coolon = fakea.join('\n')
    let don = `_________\n[\n${coolon}\n]\n_________`
    const notbot3embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Everything you can search')
        .setColor('15DD7C')
        .addField('The things you can search', don)
    msg.channel.send(notbot3embed)
}
if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix4)){
    let mayi = msg.content.split(' ')
    if(mayi.length != 2){
        msg.channel.send(`You have either less or more than two words. That either means you wrote *search on it's own or you had more than one word that you put with the command`)
    } else {
        if(fakea.includes(mayi[1])){
            let ft = a.filter(thing => thing.namer === mayi[1])
            console.log(ft)
            let secot = ft.namer
            let thirt = ft.imformation
            let fort = ft.description 
            
            const someembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(secot)
                .setColor('FF4200')
                .addField(thirt, fort)
            msg.channel.send(someembed)

        } else {
            msg.channel.send('This is not a searchable term. Use *what to see the terms that are there.')
        }
    }
}

    
    
}
})
bot4.login(process.env.token4)
```

I wrote all of it because you would be confused about the properties if I didn't. In the last part I try to get the properties of the object with the name after '*search'. Then I want to put it an embed. Here's the problem I get. On the embed all three of the things say undefined. How do I fix this

If you're confused what I'm trying to do here's what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to make a system that you can put search things(I don't know how to frase it), remove them, check which ones exist and search something. Most of it is working. But in the search part it says for all of them in the embed undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you need to use find instead of filter. Find works.